# How do I interpret the natural transformation between functors as matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, definition

I'm trying to get an intuitive understanding of adjunctions, and I've seen the following analogy/example, which I'm trying to work through. So, consider the categories of vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ and in $\mathbb R^m$ where $n > m$. Next, suppose that $F$ is a matrix in $\mathbb R^{n \times m}$ and $G$ a matrix in $\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ such that
$G F = I_m$ (left inverse) and that $G$ is the pseudoinverse of $F$, meaning that
$$
F G F = F, \
G F G = G.
$$

My question is, what exactly are the natural transformations $\varepsilon : F G \to Id_{\mathbb R^m}$ and
$\eta: Id_{\mathbb R^n} \to G F$ in this context?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'category of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$'?

Comment: A subcategory of the category of vector spaces with reals as a field, restricted to morphisms of square matrices. Isn't this a category?

Comment: The example I saw didn't quite specify as a category, it only worked with an analogy.

Comment: This would basically be a monoid, with square matrices as morphisms, and $\mathbb R^n$ as the only object.

Comment: Sure, this is a category. My confusion was that one usually names a category after its objects, and the objects of this category are not the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: As far as I know, pseudoinverses are not a very good way to picture adjunctions, see for example this post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98777/moore-penrose-inverse-as-an-adjoint

Comment: thanks a lot! Indeed, it seems to not be a good analogy.